# Passing object to an inline function in C#

Tags: c#, function

Is it possible to pass a variable (not the value of the variable) to an inline function. See example below (C# / Xamarin Forms).

For example I would like to pass one property Pressure, then in the inline function get the name of the property "Pressure" and also the value if the property "1000.0" which is then used to set a "Preference".  The code works below but I feel it is possible to simplify further.  I would be able to use this concept in all sorts of applications.

Thank you

```
void SetPreferences()
{
    void f(string key, string value) => Preferences.Set(key, value);

    //eg f("Pressure", "1000.0")
    f(nameof(Pressure), Pressure);

    //eg f("Temperature", "50.0")
    f(nameof(Temperature), Temperature);
}

void WhatIWouldLike_SetPreferences()
{
    void f(object X) => Preferences.Set(stringnameofX, stringvalueofX);

    f(Pressure);
    f(Temperature);
}
```

Comment: I'm not following.  Why not just call `Preferences.Set(nameof(Pressure), Pressure);`?

Comment: Do you mean the variable name? Or do you mean call by reference for variables?

Comment: *I would be able to use this concept in all sorts of applications.* - what, you mean making everything **stringly typed** ? Don't..

Comment: David, I could and have done that, but I have simplified to illustrate the question, and the answer would be helpful for many other parts of my code.

Comment: Christopher, I am neither wishing to pass the variable by value or reference, I wish to pass the whole variable so I can get its name and its value.

Comment: Caius, I hear you, but passing the variable as I am hoping to (which is set earlier in the code not shown) means I am not passing literals, I am passing a property/variable so that any errors would indeed be captured and prevent bugs...I think.

Comment: This is almost certainly an X-Y problem.  You're asking us to help you solve for X, but the actual problem is probably elsewhere.  Why is this such an important need? You are most likely not passing what you think you're passing in either case, in terms of passing by value/reference. Also, keep in mind that you will incur both boxing AND potential parameter capturing with this approach with absolutely zero benefit.

Comment: You could represent quantities by a `KeyValuePair<string, TValue>` or create your own type for this.

Comment: I'd hoped that `CallerArgumentExpressionAttribute` would sort this, but it looks like it didn't make it into C# 8 or 9 :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have the solution:

```
f(nameof(Temperature), Temperature);
```

Because that information can't be inferred from this:

```
f(Temperature);
```

There'd be no way for the internals of `f` to know what variable name was used, or *if one was used at all*.  What if you did this?:

```
f("123.45");
f(temperatures[0]);
f(someObj.GetTemperature());
f(await this.Temperatures.SingleOrDefaultAsync(t => t == "123.45"));
```

What would the "variable names" be?

That information isn't provided to the method, so you'll need to provide it manually if you need it.  Basically, *variables* aren't passed to the method, *values* are.

Comment: Thanks David, I guess that's why I haven't been able to find the answer, because it isn't possible... I have other very repetitive code at times that could be simplified if this was possible.

Comment: I'm pretty sure OP is looking for `void f(Expression....); f(() => Temperature)` or something like that...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: Possibly, and I've been toying with the same idea.  But wouldn't it have the same drawbacks as just passing the value?  That expression might contain anything, not just a single named variable.